# ItemsControl start at CurrentPosition = 0 instead of -1

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a custom control which is a FlipView. In it's control template, there exists a ContentControl which binds to `Items.CurrentItem` and there is a next button and a previous button which will do `Items.MoveCurrentToNext()` and vice versa. So far, so good.

My problem is that at the start, the `Items.CurrentItem` is `null` so the flipview is empty. I want it to show the first item in its Items collection.

The solution I am using currently is deriving from `Selector` and setting `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true` and setting `SelectedIndex = 0` in the constructor. This works, but is there a better way to do it? I don't need the functionality of a selector except for this workaround.

`this.Items.MoveCurrentToPosition(0);` doesn't work either. It does nothing :/

Comment: What happens when you use `MoveCurrentToPosition`? What error do you get?

Comment: No errors either? Put a breakpoint on the line, and then try to see what is the current position before and after this line is executed.

Comment: It's `-1` before and after. Note that I am setting it in constructor. I can't seem to find an event which fires after `Items` changes.

Comment: Ok, what about the Items collection? Does it have values when this line is executed? It is possible you are executing current position code before the items collection has any item to show.

Comment: @jitendragarg, yeah. I am setting it in constructor. I am such a noob, I found an `ItemsChanged` event and put it there and it works lol. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I overrided the `OnItemsChanged` method and put this `this.Items.MoveCurrentToPosition(0);` there. now it works. The reason it did not work before was because the `Items` collection was empty.

Edit: As mentioned in the comments by @jitendra garg, I should use Loaded event instead.

Comment: Good to know it works now. BTW, you should use Loaded event to handle this, if it is supposed to happen only one. ItemsChanged event will cause this to happen whenever any value is changed in the whole collection (like adding a new item, removing or renaming an item).

Comment: @jitendragarg, Thanks :)